# Match One or More Non-Digits except B or S

Tags: java, regex

I would like a Java regex to match one or more non-digits except B or S. Currently I have this:

```
\\D[^BS]+
```

However this doesn't work :/

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Need a definition: doesn't work?

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: @Doorknob: What is so difficult to understand about "one or more non-digits except B or S"?

Comment: @TimPietzcker ...I never said I didn't understand that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the digits *inside* the character class:

```
[^\\dBS]+
```

or, with anchors

```
^[^\\dBS]+$
```

to make sure the entire string is matched (but in Java, the `.matches()` method will take care of that for you).